# Off-canvas меню

Tags: html, css, javascript

Нашел подходящий вариант off-canvas меню ([Демо](http://www.sitehere.ru/examples/30.03.2014/index.html)), однако смущает то, что jQuery 976 строк. Неужели все так сложно, может, кто-то знает вариант/плагин попроще?

Comment: @rodion, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, что вы хототе. Можно, как советует [[@inferusvv](/users/6278/inferusvv)](/users/6278/inferusvv), навесить событие на кнопку и менять класс у меню. В приведенном примере сделано намного больше: там многоуровневое меню, подсветка текущей страницы, красивые анимации.

Если вас смущает именно размер кода, прогоните его через js minifier, к примеру, [вот этот](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) достаточно хорош. Если вас пугает сложность, то я не совсем тогда понимаю, почему вас не пугает тогда сложность самой [JQuery](http://jquery.com) — там [еще больше строк](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src). Если вы заботитесь о размере страницы и предполагаете, что у ее пользователей медленный интернет, тогда лучше обходиться вообще без скриптов, кто знает, с чего они будут к вам заходить?

В общем, скажите поконкретнее, что не так, и тогда можно будет что-то придумывать. Если вас просто смущает, без относительно причины, то не смущайтесь =)

Comment: Кнопка, по нажатию на ее будет выезжать off-canvas меню, а контент будет сдвигаться за пределы экрана. По повторному нажатию все будет возвращаться назад. Вот и спросил может кто-то видел решение проще, чтобы не использовать столь громоздкий код, так как все равно большинство плюшек не понадобится.